# Show that $7 \mid( 1^{47} +2^{47}+3^{47}+4^{47}+5^{47}+6^{47})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am solving this one using the fermat's little theorem but I got stuck up with some manipulations and there is no way I could tell that the residue of the sum of each term is still divisible by $7$. what could be a better approach or am I on the right track? Thanks

Comment: "sum of the residue" rather

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic or Euler's theorem?

Comment: yes.is the euler's generalization of fermat's little theorem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$6^{47} \equiv (-1)^{47} = -1^{47}\mod 7$

$5^{47} \equiv (-2)^{47} = -2^{47}\mod 7$

$4^{47} \equiv (-3)^{47} = -3^{47}\mod 7$

Hence $ 1^{47} +2^{47}+3^{47}+4^{47}+5^{47}+6^{47} \equiv 0 \mod 7$.

Comment: thanks...I just remembered that 6 is congruent to -1 mod 7.

Answer (score 7):

One more solution.

By Fermat's Little Theorem,
$a^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for $a \not\equiv 0$.  Thus,
$$
a^{48} = \left(a^6\right)^8 \equiv 1^8 = 1 \pmod{7}
$$
for each $a \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 6\}$.

As a consequence, $a^{47} \equiv a^{-1}$, so
$$
\begin{align}
1^{47} + 2^{47} + 3^{47} + 4^{47} + 5^{47} + 6^{47} &\equiv 1^{-1} + 2^{-1} + 3^{-1} + 4^{-1} + 5^{-1} + 6^{-1} \\
&\equiv 1 + 4 + 5 + 2 + 3 + 6 \\
&\equiv 0 \pmod{7}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** Make use of the fact that
$$(a+b) \vert (a^{2n+1} + b^{2n+1})$$

Answer (score 3):

The map $x \mapsto x^{47}$ is injective on the nonzero classes mod $7$ because they form a group of order $6$. Hence this map is a permutation and so

$1^{47} +2^{47}+3^{47}+4^{47}+5^{47}+6^{47} \equiv 1+2+3+4+5+6 \equiv 0 \mod 7$.

Comment: how can we say that the map you gave is injective and I can't visualize why the nozero classes of groups of order 6 forms a group, in what operation? thanks and I apologize for not understanding it completely

Comment: Since $7$ is a prime, the product of two nonmultiples of $7$ is never a multiple a $7$, so you have a group under modular multiplication. The kernel of the map is the set of numbers such that $x^{47}=1$ but only $1$ is in there because of Lagrange's theorem, given that the order of the group is 6.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427744/showing-that-1k2k-dots-nk-is-divisible-by-nn1-over-2), $$\sum_{1\le r\le 6}r^{2k+1}$$ is divisible by  $$\frac{6(6+1)}2=21$$

Comment: (+1), Expected this as you were the one who proved $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}|1^k+ \dots n^k$.:)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Find the mod cycle of 7 with the powers of each of the numbers. Then simply add them together.