# Proof that there is no positive integer n such that $n+2 | 1^k + 2^k + \dots + n^k$ where $k$ is an odd integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof that there is no positive integer $n$ such that $n + 2 | 1^k + 2^k + \dots + n^k$ where $k$ is an odd integer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427744/showing-that-1k2k-dots-nk-is-divisible-by-nn1-over-2

Comment: @InsideOut:  $2+2=4$ does not divide $1^1+2^1=3$

Comment: I read $k+2$.. I delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using modular arithmetic ($\text{mod }n+2$);
$$\begin{align}
1^k+2^k+\dots+(n-1)^k+n^k
&\equiv1^k+2^k+\dots+(-3)^k+(-2)^k\\
&\equiv\begin{cases}1+\left(\frac{n}2+1\right)^k&n\text{ even}\\1&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}\\
\end{align}$$