# When is $\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^n =0 \bmod \dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have tried to creat such formula related to divisibility using triangulair numbers and series , I have got the following problem  such that I ask when is $S_n(m)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^n =0 \bmod \dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}$ ? , My simple attempt without using any complicated solution, I got that $n$ must be odd positive and integer and $m$ must be arbitrary positive integer , such that I treated only the first case when both $n$ and $m$ are odd we may group the terms of $ S_n(m)$ as follows, and as $n$ is also odd we see by expanding the binomial that : $S_n(m)=m^n+\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)/2}(i^n+(m-i)^{n})$ this means only that  $m | S_n(m)$ but How I can follow this idea to pove that: $m(m+1)/2 | S_n(m)$ if what i have claimed is true  ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427744/showing-that-1k2k-dots-nk-is-divisible-by-nn1-over-2

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: @zeraouliarafik FYI, on a closely related note, you may be interested in reading about [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). As you can see in that Wikipedia article, with $a = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, the sums of the odd powers can be defined as polynomials, possibly divided by a constant integer, of $a$, with all of the sums of powers $\gt 1$ actually having a factor of $a^2$ (apart from possibly cases where the denominator, e.g., $3$ or $5$, is a factor of $a$).